# Set custom user agent on rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, turbolinks, rspec3, turbolinks-ios

I am developing iOS app using [turbolinks-ios](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios) and Rails variant.

In my iOS app, I set custom user agent `iPadApp` and detect that on Rails `application controller` is using `request.user_agent.try(:index, 'iPadApp')` for setting `variant` to `tablet` (because by views are like `foo.html+tablet.haml`).

My app is working fine and now I am trying to write feature tests for my app but can't properly set user agent. I tried [this](http://www.headshift.com/labs/2012/02/14/cucumber-to-test-mobile-in-a-rails-project/) post that actually is [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399156/using-cucumber-capybara-in-rails-3-how-do-i-set-a-custom-user-agent-string) but I see that it does not set `request.user_agent` instead (`page.driver.browser.header(key, value)`) set query parameter with in `request.params`.

In my controller test I simply use `request.user_agent = 'iPadApp'` to set user agent which is working fine.

How can I configure testing request so that I can use `request.user_agent.try(:index, 'iPadApp')`?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Which driver are you using with capybara?

Comment: @TomWalpole No explicit driver given. So I think it uses default driver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're not specifying a driver Capybara should be using rack_test.  With the rack_test driver you can set the user agent header, in your test code before calling `visit`, with

```
page.driver.header('User-Agent', 'the user agent string you want')
```

That should then make request.user_agent accessible in your application code.

A different solution would be register a specific driver for your ipad tests

```
Capybara.register_driver(:ipad_rack_test) do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new(app, :headers => { 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'User agent string' })
end
```

and then specify your driver as :ipad_rack_test

Comment: Your solution work though I found that `page.driver.header` call `page.driver.browser.header` (source code)[https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb] . I don't know why last day it did no work ( I just restart my server). Is there any way to pass `User-Agent` as attribute as option of `visit` method? So that, instead of set header before every visit a can pass this option. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course I can override `visit` method where I can set `header` depending on passing `options`.

Comment: No there is no way to pass it to visit without you overriding `visit` yourself.  A simpler/cleaner solution would probably be to just put the header setting in a before block, so it's run before every test (or tests you tag with specific  metadata)

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon  If you need this for a lot of tests see the section I added to the answer about registering a driver specifically for it.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `page'

Comment: @Eddie Then you're not calling it in your test code which is what the answer talks about, or you haven't correctly installed Capybara for your tests.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to this, if you are looking to set the user agent for all of your testing. You can do something like this in your spec_helper.rb config section (chrome user agent as an example)

```
config.before(:each) do
  Capybara.page.driver.header('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36.')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment or edit, I was forced to make a new answer. Although the above is correct, for the top where he has `page.driver.header('User-Agent', 'the user agent string you want')`, I had to use `Capybara.page.driver.header('User-Agent', 'the user-agent string you want')`.

Hope this helps.